# Remove / character from my DDL query

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am using below query to get DDL of my function without getting the user name. In my query I am getting `/` slash also and I don't want to see the `/` too. How can I get rid off this `/` ?

```
FUNCTION_NAME= "EMP"
USER_NAME="USER1"



SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( 
             REPLACE ( 
                  dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('FUNCTION', '" + function_name+ @"')
                      , '""" + User_name + @""".')
                     ,'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') 

FROM dual
```

**result:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "EMP"
(str_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN AS
-- validating ###-##-#### format
BEGIN
  IF TRANSLATE(str_in, '0123456789A','AAAAAAAAAAB') = 'AAA-AA-AAAA' THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  END IF;
  RETURN FALSE;
END ssn_candy;
/
```

**Expected result**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "EMP"
(str_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN AS
-- validating ###-##-#### format
BEGIN
  IF TRANSLATE(str_in, '0123456789A','AAAAAAAAAAB') = 'AAA-AA-AAAA' THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  END IF;
  RETURN FALSE;
END ssn_candy;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression removes the empty spaces at the beginning of each line. You can modify it to `'^(\s+|/)'` to remove the slash at the beginning of the line.

You can also try the TRIM function instead of Regular Expressions, if your intention is to solely remove the slash.

```
trim (trailing '/'  from 'source string')
```